# '... is very good quality' VS '... is OF [a] very good quality' + article

Tags: prepositions, articles, indefinite-article

I've got two questions regarding this sentence for a grammar book:

> The jacket you bought is very good quality.

1. Would it be correct to say: '*This jacket is **OF** very good quality.*'?
2. Would it be correct to say: '*This jacket is [of] **A** very good quality.*'?

If any of the above is correct, is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Their products are of very high quality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115658/their-products-are-of-very-high-quality)